# NvFBCPlugin Window preventing you from restarting

Tags: windows-10, nvidia

On my Windows 10 machine every restart I get "NvFBCPluginWindow is preventing you from restarting".  The only help I find on this is 3+ years old suggestion to press alt+z.  That's not helpful.  Anyone else know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Doh!  turns out this is because I upgraded to a Radeon card and still had all those Nvidia programs still running.  I hope this helps someone else in this situation.

[image]

[image]